# How to change entire navigatorbar background color on xPage?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, xpages

Here is my xPage with just navigator bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

    <xe:navbar id="navbarBottom" 
    fixed="fixed-bottom" 
    headingStyle="font-weight: bold;" 
    pageWidth="fixed" 
    headingText="Testpage" 
    title="Testpage"
    style="background-color:red;">

    <xe:this.navbarAfterLinks>
        <xe:basicLeafNode title="Page1" label="Page1" href="/Page1.xsp"></xe:basicLeafNode>
        <xe:basicLeafNode title="Page2" label="Page2" href="/Page2.xsp"></xe:basicLeafNode>
        <xe:basicLeafNode title="Page3" label="Page3" href="/Page1.xsp"></xe:basicLeafNode>
    </xe:this.navbarAfterLinks>
    </xe:navbar>
</xp:view>
```

I'd like to change its background color. But style="background-color:red;" works only for After links. I cannot really figure it out to what element should I apply the style. Inspecting elements in e.g. Chrome just confuses me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should solve your problem:

### XPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/custom.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    </xp:this.resources>

    <xe:navbar id="navbarBottom" fixed="fixed-bottom"
        headingStyle="font-weight: bold;" pageWidth="fixed" headingText="Testpage"
        title="Testpage" styleClass="navbar-custom">

        <xe:this.navbarAfterLinks>
            <xe:basicLeafNode title="Page1" label="Page1" href="/Page1.xsp">
            </xe:basicLeafNode>
            <xe:basicLeafNode title="Page2" label="Page2" href="/Page2.xsp">
            </xe:basicLeafNode>
            <xe:basicLeafNode title="Page3" label="Page3" href="/Page1.xsp">
            </xe:basicLeafNode>
        </xe:this.navbarAfterLinks>
    </xe:navbar>

</xp:view>
```

### CSS-File

```
.navbar-custom {
    background-color:red;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inspect  elements in browser and checked their classes. Put the below code to your css file. It will change background color of your navbar.

```
.xspNavbar .container-fluid {
    background-color: red;
}
```